# BS "find_all" method does not match all target

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I use `find_all` method on this page *beautiful soup* doesn't find all targets.

This code:

```
len(mySoup.find_all('div', {'class': 'lo-liste row'}))
```

Returns 1, yet there are 4.

[This](https://www.ubaldi.com/offres/jeu-de-3-disques-feutres-electrolux--ma-92ca565jeud-4b9yz--727536.php) is the soup url.

Comment: Please do not use external links as the only source, please provide the HTML snippet you were trying to parse in your question. External page can change with time and different users can see different code.

Answer (score 0):

When i looked in source code of given link i found there are only 1 div with class name "lo-liste row" other three div is having class name as follows "lo-liste row not-first-ligne" so that's why you got only 1 as output.
try following code

```
len(soup.findAll('div', {'class': ['lo-liste row','not-first-ligne']}))


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.ubaldi.com/offres/jeu-de-3-disques-feutres-electrolux--ma-92ca565jeud-4b9yz--727536.php")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(len(soup.findAll('div', {'class': ['lo-liste row','not-first-ligne']})))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `find_all` DOES correctly match all targets.

The first product has `class=lo-liste row`

The next 3 products have `class=lo-liste row not-first-ligne`

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.ubaldi.com/offres/jeu-de-3-disques-feutres-electrolux--ma-92ca565jeud-4b9yz--727536.php'

response = requests.get(url)
mySoup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


for product in mySoup.find_all('div', {'class': 'lo-liste row'}):
    print (product.find('a').find_next('span').text.strip())


for product in mySoup.find_all('div', {'class': 'lo-liste row not-first-ligne'}):
    print (product.find('a').find_next('span').text.strip())


# or to combine those 2 for loops into 1
#for product in mySoup.findAll('div', {'class': ['lo-liste row','not-first-ligne']}):
    #print (product.find('a').find_next('span').text.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
SOS Accessoire
Stortle
Groupe-Dragon
Asdiscount
```

Answer (score 0):

Use select instead. It will match on all 4 for that class.

```
items = soup.select('.lo-liste.row')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expression `re` to find the element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'https://www.ubaldi.com/offres/jeu-de-3-disques-feutres-electrolux--ma-92ca565jeud-4b9yz--727536.php'

html= requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
print(len(soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile('lo-liste row'))))
```

Output:

```
4
```